# Set Linux terminal foreground color prior to login

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, colors, linux-terminal

I'm wanting to set the foreground color of a Linux terminal (outside of any GUI). I'm using Gallium with its multi-user target, which opens straight to the terminal rather than the GUI.

I've tried a systemctl service, to no avail.

I've experimented briefly with terminfo, but I don't know enough about what to change, or where to place it. The documentation is sparse/confusing to me.

Is this possible?

Comment: I would guess (I have not tried), it is done via the files you might have sitting in `/etc/terminal-colors.d` .. see this link.. please let us know what you find.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminal-colors.d.5.html

Comment: The `/etc/terminal-colors.d` folder does not exist in Gallium.

Comment: To be clear, I don't mind trying terminal-colors.d, but it's not clear what the color name should be since it's utility-specific.